# MySQL query LIKE getting error

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-like

I want to search for people whose name start with letter A using LIKE query but I'm getting errors. What query should I type in order to get results based on people whose name start with a particular letter or not with that letter?

Comment: What is the error?  What is the query you are trying?

Answer (score 3):

Get result where name starts with a specific letter

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
```

Get result where name DOES NOT start with a specific letter

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name NOT LIKE 'A%'
```